# TextMeshPro can not be resolved as a class in visual studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tmp

I start to use TextMesh Pro in unity3D 2018 to render text and it works well when I set it up in inspector. But by the time I try to reference it in the script in visual studio 2017, I find the vs always warn me there is no such a class. Could anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Are you referencing the TMPro namespace? `using TMPro;`

Comment: Yes, I do. Its still not working. Even the tmp example scripts report TextMeshPro can not be resolved.

Comment: It appears there is an issue with TMPro. https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-textmesh-pro-in-script.542853

Comment: You saved my day! No issues anymore after I upgraded my visual studio 2017 to the latest version.

Comment: @bolkay you could write an answer to let me accept it.

Comment: I have added an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade Unity to the latest version. It appears there is a problem with TMPro.
An issue related to this [has been discussed on the Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-textmesh-pro-in-script.542853)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you need to use the namespace from text mesh pro **"using TMPro"** and variables look like this **"public TextMeshProUGUI aTextMeshProField;"**

Comment: I added "using TMPro" and its still not working, including "public TextMeshProUGUI aTextMeshProField;"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and none of the following worked for me: updating Visual Studio 2019 through Visual Studio Installer, updating to latest Unity LTS 2020.3 and the visual studio editor package on Unity Package Manager.

Then I saw there were issues reported years ago regarding namespaces and packages [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-textmesh-pro-in-script.542853/), to I went to Unity > Edit > Preferences > External Tools and I unticked "Generate .csproj files for Registry Packages", and that did the trick for me.